# Do we need a new close reason of "Abandoned"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This is basically a resurrection of [How should we define "Abandoned" as a close reason?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2468/how-should-we-define-abandoned-as-a-close-reason), but given [Reminder: Unanswered + Time != Too Localised](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6492/reminder-unanswered-time-too-localised?cb=1), I think we need to actually revisit this.

Should we add a new close reason for "Abandoned" with a specific message related to abandonment.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv

Comment: Actually, I think the they are re-hauling the entire flag and close system..

Comment: @Seth If that's the case, then it should be listed as an overhaul not just the two or so specified close reasons.  I haven't seen anything to that effect on MSO, except forjust those items in that one link.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that isn't covered by Too Localized?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: Also Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6492/reminder-unanswered-time-too-localised?cb=1

Comment: That's about closing questions that are too old. Abandoned questions are pretty easy to determine, I just flag them Too Localized.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op